# Generate sort by list

Tags: php, mysql, database, auto-generate

I have a data like this :

```
   car_id | price_id | transmission_id | group_id | image_id
   =======|==========|=================|==========|=============
 1. CAR A | $20/hour | Automatic       | GROUP A  | image_1.jpg
 2. CAR B | $30/hour | Automatic       | GROUP B  | image_2.jpg
 3. CAR C | $40/hour | Manual          | GROUP C  | image_3.jpg
 4. CAR D | $20/hour | Manual          | GROUP A  | image_4.jpg
 5. CAR E | $30/hour | Manual          | GROUP B  | image_5.jpg
 6. CAR F | $40/hour | Automatic       | GROUP D  | image_6.jpg
```

So, the lists can be selected (choose) by "group_id" or "transmission_id". 
User can tick and automatically generate result sort by :

- Group A,B,C,D
- Transmission Automatic,Manual
- Group + Transmission

The result shown on the same page. Is it possible if I don't want to use MySQL?

Comment: What do you want to use?

Comment: Yes, just use PostgreSQL...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912353/is-there-an-alternative-to-mysql)

Comment: Why not MySQL ? Just asking. Also, don't tell me you're storing data in `price_id` like this column. Doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Is it possible to use only javascript to generate the data? Any example? @derape

Comment: Because I don't really know how to use mysql. And @Raptor, is there any problem with my column?

Comment: Hi @Chin, normally we only store the value into column `20` as integer instead of `$20/hour`, which favors sorting, comparison, filtering & indexing.

Comment: Additionally, MySQL is an useful free DBMS software. Try learning it from basics.